# Multitouch as3 problems

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch

I have a little problem with multitouch in as3.
Recently started a project in connection with my student practice.
This is to be a small game for android.
Are used to control two virtual joysticks and that's the problem with them.
As long as I use one of them or the other separately all works very well. However, when I try to use two at the same time, one of them is blocked and the object which moves begin to move in a random way and I can not control it.

Here is my code:

joystick.as:

```
package com.controls {

import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

import com.controls.JoystickKnob;
import com.Hero;
import com.Fire;

import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

public class Joystick extends MovieClip {

    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; 

    private var my_x:Number;
    private var my_y:Number;

    private var knob:JoystickKnob;
    private var hero:Hero;
    private var fire:Fire;

    private var knob_tween:TweenLite;

    public function Joystick(margin_left, margin_bottom, hero_mc) {

        var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
        circle.graphics.beginFill(0x696969);
        circle.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 60);
        circle.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(circle);

        my_x = margin_left;
        my_y = margin_bottom;
        hero = hero_mc;

        if (stage) {
            init();
        } else {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }       
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void {


        if (hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE)) {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }

        this.x = my_x + this.width / 2;
        this.y = stage.stageHeight - my_y - this.height / 2;

        knob = new JoystickKnob();
        knob.x = 0;
        knob.y = 0;

        knob.origin_x = 0;
        knob.origin_y = 0;

        addChild(knob);

        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin, true);
        knob.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove, true);
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd, true);

        knob.buttonMode = true;
    }

    private function onTouchBegin(event:TouchEvent):void {

        knob.x = this.mouseX;
        knob.y = this.mouseY;

        onTouchMove(null);

    }

    private function onTouchMove(event:TouchEvent):void {

        if (knob_tween) {
            knob_tween.kill();
        }

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, knobMoved);
        knob.startDrag(false, new Rectangle( -  this.width /2, - this.height /2, this.width, this.height));

    }

    private function knobMoved(event:Event):void {

        // LEFT OR RIGHT
        if (knob.x > 15) {
            hero.move_right = true;
            hero.move_left = false;

        } else if (knob.x < -15) {
            hero.move_right = false;
            hero.move_left = true;

        } else {
            hero.move_right = false;
            hero.move_left = false;

        }

        // UP OR DOWN
        if (knob.y > 15) {
            hero.move_down = true;
            hero.move_up = false;

        } else if (knob.y < -15) {
            hero.move_down = false;
            hero.move_up = true;

        } else {
            hero.move_down = false;
            hero.move_up = false;
        }
    }

    private function onTouchEnd(event:TouchEvent):void {

        knob.stopDrag();

        hero.move_left = false;
        hero.move_up = false;
        hero.move_right = false;
        hero.move_down = false;


        if (this.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)) {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, knobMoved);
        }


        mover();
    }

    private function mover():void {

        knob_tween = new TweenLite(knob, 0.5, {x: knob.origin_x, y:knob.origin_y, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
    }
}
```

}

joystickKnob.as:

```
package com.controls {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class JoystickKnob extends MovieClip {       

    private var _origin_x:Number;
    private var _origin_y:Number;       

    private var knob:Class;

    public function JoystickKnob() {

        var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
         circle.graphics.beginFill(0x32CD32);
         circle.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 35);
         circle.graphics.endFill();
         addChild(circle);
    }

    public function get origin_x():Number {

        return _origin_x;
    }

    public function set origin_x(o_x:Number):void {

        _origin_x = o_x;
    }

    public function get origin_y():Number {

        return _origin_x;
    }

    public function set origin_y(o_y:Number):void {

        _origin_y = o_y;
    }
}
```

}

Second joystick code looks the same, except that it is stored in files joystick2.as, joystickKnob2.as.

This is the main class of my program:

```
package com {

import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import com.controls.Joystick;
import com.controls.Joystick2;

import com.Hero;
import com.Fire;

public class MyApp extends MovieClip {

    private var joystick:Joystick;
    private var hero:Hero;
    private var joystick2:Joystick2;
    private var fire:Fire;

    public function MyApp() {

        hero = new Hero();
        hero.x = stage.stageWidth/1.7;
        hero.y = stage.stageHeight/1.7;
        addChild(hero);

        fire = new Fire();
        fire.x = stage.stageWidth/1.7;
        fire.y = stage.stageHeight/1.7;
        addChild(fire);

        joystick = new Joystick(-350, 100, hero);
        addChild(joystick);

        joystick2 = new Joystick2(600, 100, fire);
        addChild(joystick2);

    }
}
```

}

When using the two joysticks at the same time, the problem also occurs with the knob graphics - instead move in a specific area, one of them almost always moves to the other end of the screen, near the area of the second joystick.

Has anyone of you already encountered such a problem and knows how to remedy it?

Best regards and thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;` does not support multiple fingers as written in de documentation:

`For user interaction with multiple points of contact (such as several fingers moving across a touch screen at the same time) use the related GestureEvent, PressAndTapGestureEvent, and TransformGestureEvent classes. And, use the properties and methods of these classes to construct event handlers that respond to the user touching the device.`

so you want `Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;`

Comment: Yes! That was it!
Thank you very much for your help. You saved my life.
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

This post shows up when searching for info on touch_point so I want to make sure it's correct.

TOUCH_POINT does support multiple touch points.  Each touch is unique and given a unique id.  You can have 100s of simultaneous touches.

TOUCH_POINT is what you use if you want to code your own touch handlers.  GESTURE is TOUCH_POINTs handled for you.  GESTURE decides if the touchpoints are swiping, tapping, etc.  TOUCH_POINT is like a mouse event - the raw event.